# WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment

Tags: spring, hibernate, wildfly

I am deploying my Spring application on wildfly-16.0.0.FINAL using Java 11. Locally, I am able to deploy successfully but when deploying in Linux VM, getting below error:

```
10:24:03,215 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."application.war".DEPENDENCIES: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."application.war".DEPENDENCIES: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment “application.war"

at org.jboss.as.server@8.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:183)

at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1738)

at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1700)

at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1558)

at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)

at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)

at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)

at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)

at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found

at org.jboss.as.jaxrs@16.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsSpringProcessor.deploy(JaxrsSpringProcessor.java:202)

at org.jboss.as.server@8.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)

... 8 more

Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found

at org.jboss.as.jaxrs@16.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsSpringProcessor.getResteasySpringVirtualFile(JaxrsSpringProcessor.java:132)

at org.jboss.as.jaxrs@16.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsSpringProcessor.deploy(JaxrsSpringProcessor.java:198)

... 9 more

Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found

at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1529)

at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1430)

at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1437)

at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1268)

at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1231)

at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:726)

at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:843)

at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:246)

at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:176)

at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:346)

at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:317)

at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:283)

at org.jboss.vfs@3.2.14.Final//org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem.<init>(JavaZipFileSystem.java:90)

at org.jboss.vfs@3.2.14.Final//org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mountZip(VFS.java:360)

at org.jboss.as.jaxrs@16.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsSpringProcessor.getResteasySpringVirtualFile(JaxrsSpringProcessor.java:112)

... 10 more
```

I googled but did not find any appropriate solution for this.

Comment: It looks like some library is corrupted.

Comment: Hi @JamesR.Perkins,

Any idea which jar is corrupted. Debugged a lot but did not find any jar corrupted.

Comment: Not too sure know. If possible I'd try rebuilding the project and redeploying. Otherwise you're likely going to have to debug the `org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsSpringProcessor`.

Comment: There is no issue with jar file corrupted.

The issue is with resteasy-spring module integration in wildfly 16.0.0.FINAL. There is a boolean flag that needs to be disabled in the web.xml config. 


<!-- Disable resteasy-spring module/integration in jboss(wildfly-16.0.0.Final) -->
    <context-param> 
        <param-name>org.jboss.as.jaxrs.enableSpringIntegration</param-name> 
        <param-value>false</param-value> 
    </context-param>